# Best Traversing Strategy / Logic Help Needed

Tags: java, computer-science, programming-logic

**Background:** Here is the scenario, imagine I have a little Robot. I give this robot a Map, and I want him to traverse the map, after doing so, I want the Robot to tell me the shortest possible path on the map. So here is an example of a Map:

[image: Robot Map]

**Difficulties:** The Robot is given the Map in the form of a HashMap. For the above map it will be something like this:

```
A > B, E
B > A, C, E
C > B, E
D > E
E > A, B, C, D, F
F > E
```

So node [ A ] has neighbours [ B ] and [ E ] and so on. The Robot can only know the neighbours of the node it is currently at.

So only when at node [ A ] will the Robot know that the neighbours of [ A ] are [ B ] and [ E ]. The Robot has no way of knowing what neighbours [ B ] has unless it is at [ B ], once there, the Robot can call the **getNeighbouringNodes() method** to find out the neighbours (Returned to Robot as a List).

**Current Thinking:** At the moment my logic for getting the shortest path from Start to Exit is as follows:

Essentially, it is a breadth first traversal. Once at the start node [ A ], I get the list of neighbouring nodes, then visit first neighbour in the list [ B ].

Once at [ B ] I call the **isThisAnExitNode() method** to check that [ B ] is an exit node, if yes, write my short path, and exist the map. If no, I go back to node [ A ] and grab the next neighbour of [ A ] which is [ E ].

Do same with [ E ], now if no Exit node was found, I move onto [ B ] to explore its neighbours.

I think you get the idea.

My question is, am I doing it right? Is there a better, more efficient way than my method of traversal?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank You.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So long as you know your starting node (which in this case you do), you can use [Dijkstra's Algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra%27s_algorithm) to find the shortest path.  Although you didn't specify if there are weights for the paths, it accounts for that as well so long as there are no negative values allowed in the weights.

This uses the assumption that the robot has some form of memory.  It isn't able to see parts of the map that it is not adjacent to, but memorizing the vertices and their weights is a must for any sort of efficient algorithm.

Comment: Haha love how you thought ahead about the weights of the paths. The part one of my problem ignores all weightings and is simply about finding the shortest path. The second part will involve a battery charge (percentage) at each node. But I will create another Question when the time comes. Thank You, I will try coding Dijkstra's Algorithm in Java.